# ListView content not appearing - Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to show a list of weeks, and each week can have multiple Events and Recoveries (`GroupedWeeksModel` class). The issue is that the content in `<ListView.ItemTemplate>` is not appearing, and the `<ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>` content is appearing with the wrong text colour.
[image: Events Page]

EventsPage.xaml file:

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <ListView BackgroundColor="DeepPink" IsGroupingEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedWeeks}" GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding DateString}" SeparatorVisibility="None" VerticalOptions="Start" x:Name="weeksList" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell Height="60">
                        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="{Binding DateString}" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell Height="75">
                        <StackLayout HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="200">
                                    
                            <Label> Why isn't this text appearing? </Label>

                            <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Events}">
                                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ui:MaterialCard HeightRequest="70" Margin="20, 0, 20, 5" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="Red">
                                            <StackLayout Padding="10, 0, 0, 0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" WidthRequest="30" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                                    <ui:MaterialLabel TextColor="White" Text="{Binding ShortMonth}"/>
                                                    <ui:MaterialLabel FontSize="Large" TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Day}"/>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                                    <ui:MaterialLabel LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                                    <ui:MaterialLabel TextColor="White" Text="{Binding FullDate}"/>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </ui:MaterialCard>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Recoveries}">
                                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ui:MaterialCard HeightRequest="70" Margin="20, 0, 20, 5" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="Green">
                                            <StackLayout Padding="10, 0, 0, 0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" WidthRequest="30" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                                    <ui:MaterialLabel TextColor="White" Text="{Binding ShortMonth}"/>
                                                    <ui:MaterialLabel FontSize="Large" TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Day}"/>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                                    <ui:MaterialLabel LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" TextColor="White" Text="{Binding RecoveryType.Name}"/>
                                                    <ui:MaterialLabel TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Date}"/>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </ui:MaterialCard>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell> 
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

EventsPage.xaml.cs file:

```
public partial class EventsPage : ContentPage
{
    public EventsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new EventsViewModel();
    }
}
```

EventsViewModel:

```
public class EventsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<GroupedWeeksModel> GroupedWeeks { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<GroupedWeeksModel>();

    public EventsViewModel()
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await InitializeAsync());
    }

    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        GroupedWeeks = await LoadEventsAndRecoveries();
    }
}

public class GroupedWeeksModel
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string DateString => // Some Logic
    public ObservableCollection<EventResponse> Events { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<EventResponse>();
    public ObservableCollection<RecoveryResponse> Recoveries { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<RecoveryResponse>();
}
```

Comment: the first issue I see is that your `ViewCell` has a height of 75, but it's contents are much larger than that.  So the contents may just be cutting off because the cell is too small

Comment: @Jason Increasing the `ViewCell` height doesn't help.

Comment: The code you provided may be incomplete. Can you provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example? For specific steps, you can refer to this link: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @SeanHe-MSFT I'm not sure what else I should be including.

Comment: I found my issue though.
The `GroupedWeeksModel` class needs to be set like below in order to use it for a grouped list.
```public class GroupedWeeksModel : ObservableCollection<EventResponse>
{
    ...
}```

I ended up creating a joint model for the `EventResponse` and `RecoveryResponse`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to found my issue, I just need to combine the `EventResponse` and `RecoveryResponse` models and change the `GroupedWeeksModel` like so:

```
public class GroupedWeeksModel : ObservableCollection<EventAndRecoveryResponse>
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string DateString => // Some Logic
}
```

This seems to be the required way for binding to a Grouped ListWeek.